# Do i have to always wrap an argument to a promise when doing promise -then-catch

Tags: javascript, promise, mysql2

Background on the question, Im using express,node and mysql2.

Basically, I'm trying to ping a database to verify the connection. By using the Promise-then-catch syntax, I have to pass `conn` to the next `then` as `.ping()` do not return anything, and i wont be able to release the connection without this way of writting.

My question is this,

```
const p0 = Promise.resolve(conn) 

const p0 = conn
```

both works, are there any reason why i should wrap it in promise? Will there be any issue if i dont do so?

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');


const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST || 'localhost',
  port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT) || 3306,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME || 'playstore',
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  connectionLimit: parseInt(process.env.DB_CONNECTION_LIMIT) || 4,
  timezone: '+08:00',
});

const SQL_GET_APP_CATEGORIES = 'select distinct category from apps ';

pool
  .getConnection()
  .then((conn) => {
    console.info('ping-ing DB');
    const p0 = Promise.resolve(conn);
    const p1 = conn.ping();
    return Promise.all([p0, p1]);
  })
  .then((results) => {
    const conn = results[0];
    //Release connection
    conn.release();
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Running on http://localhost:${PORT}`));
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(`Cannot start server ${e}`);
  });
```

Comment: *"are there any reason why i should wrap it in promise?"* In short, no. Returning a non-promise from the `then` callback will still return a promise from `then`, which is resolved with the returned callback value. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value

Comment: For the particular question, see the duplicate (no, you don't need `Promise.resolve`). For other (better) ways to solve the problem wit `ping` not passing through a value, see [How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
pool
  .getConnection()
  .then((conn) => {
    console.info('ping-ing DB');
    const p0 = Promise.resolve(conn);
    const p1 = conn.ping();
    return Promise.all([p0, p1]);
  })
```

You can write it this way:

```
pool
  .getConnection()
  .then((conn) => {
    console.info('ping-ing DB');
    return conn.ping().then(() => conn);
  })
```

Which just basically says that when `conn.ping()` resolves, you want to make the resolved value of the returned promise be `conn`.  Or, if it rejects, the returned promise will be rejected.

---

The way you were doing it, there is no reason to wrap it in a promise.  You can pass a value to `Promise.all()` if you want as in:

```
return Promise.all([conn.ping(), conn]);
```

But, my recommendation at the beginning of this answer would be cleaner since you're not interested in the resolved value from `conn.ping()` and you only have one promise (thus there's no real reason to use `Promise.all()` with only a single promise).